# How can I automatically create a phpBB session when someone logs onto my website? (Single sign-on)

Tags: php, session, single-sign-on, session-state, phpbb3

I currently have a website with user sessions and a phpBB discussion board. I want to merge the website and phpBB session functionality so that if a users logs in on the main website I want to create the phpBB session automatically.

I can't find the right tutorial/example on the internet that fits my needs – I can only find examples the other way around.

Is there a recommended way of handling this issue?

Comment: There's also a very similar question here: [How can I integrate users' logins from my site into phpBB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279655/how-can-i-integrate-users-logins-from-my-site-into-phpbb)

Answer (score 2):

In the olden days you were very much advised against integrating phpBB into your own login system since phpBB was a complex piece of software (still is, of course) and not very extensible, but the tides have changed since phpBB3 and they made it more extensible, so what are the options?

### Authentication Plugin (for phpBB 3.0)

https://wiki.phpbb.com/Authentication_plugins

> phpBB3 supports external authentication plugins that can be used to replace the traditional database-based user authentication which is still available as the db authentication method.
>
> The plugins are implemented as dynamically loadable PHP modules in the `includes/auth/` directory. Each module is identified by its method identifier. The identifier is used in the module name and it is a suffix of every function declared in the module.
>
> To add a new authentication method (let’s call it `foo`), you have to create the source file `auth_method.php` (`auth_foo.php` in our example) in the `includes/auth/` directory. This source file should provide a number of functions. The only mandatory function in the authentication module is the `login_method()` function (`login_foo()` in our example). All other methods are optional.
>
> As soon as the new authentication module has been created in the `includes/auth/` directory, it can be selected as the desired authentication method in the Administration Control Panel under Client communication/Authentication settings.

I was unable to find a working example of this feature but with some programming knowledge you should be able to build your own.

### Authentication Provider (for phpBB 3.1+)

https://area51.phpbb.com/docs/dev/3.1.x/extensions/tutorial_authentication.html#authentication-providers (with examples)

> An authentication provider that comes with phpBB requires a minimum of two files: a class and an entry in `phpBB/config/auth_providers.yml` file. Authentication providers that are part of an extension instead of requiring an entry in `phpBB/config/auth_providers.yml` must provide their own yaml file defining the service in addition to all normal requirements of an extension.

The phpBB Wiki-entry on authentication providers comes with an example, so I recommend starting with that one if your board is on phpBB 3.1 or above.